# what's the performance difference between int and varchar for primary keys

Tags: sql, primary-key

I need to create a primary key scheme for a system that will need peer to peer replication. So I'm planning to combine a unique system ID and a sequential number in some way to come up with unique ID's. I want to make sure I'll never run out of ID's, so I'm thinking about using a varchar field, since I could always add another character if I start running out. But I've read that integers are better optimized for this. So I have some questions...

1) Are integers really better optimized? And if they are, how much of a performance difference is there between varchars and integers? I'm going to use firebird for now. But I may switch later. Or possibly support multiple db's. So I'm looking for generalizations, if that's possible.

2) If integers are significantly better optimized, why is that? And is it likely that varchars will catch up in the future, so eventually it won't matter anyway?

My varchar keys won't have any meaning, except for the unique system ID part. But I may want to obscure that somehow. Also, I plan to efficiently use all the bits of each character. I don't, for example, plan to code the integer 123 as the character string "123". So I don't think varchars will require more space than integers.

Comment: How many rows do you expect to store?

Comment: Most systems will be small, and will probably generate under 50,000 rows per year. But it's possible I'll add features that will need to store a lot more. Also, some systems will consolidate data from a lot of different systems. And it could potentially be from thousands of systems. So rather than try to figure out a maximum # of rows, I'm thinking I'm better off just planning for a really big number. Unless the performance hit is too much. Then I'll reconsider.

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL, according to Alexey [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/01/24/enum-fields-vs-varchar-vs-int-joined-table-what-is-faster/), the answer is surprisingly "not much".  He concludes:

> So, if you have an application and you need to have some table field with a small set of possible values, I'd still suggest you to use ENUM, but now we can see that performance hit may not be as large as you expect. Though again a lot depends on your data and queries.

Comment: The test in the article you linked to is not exactly analogous to his situation, since the field was being used needed to end up a string somehow.  His test was comparing putting the string in a varchar to putting a uid in an int AND joining to another table to get the corresponding string.  In other words, he wasn't comparing using an int as a key vs using a varchar as a key, as the OP is asking about.  Big difference.

Comment: Thanks, that's starting to give me an idea of what to expect. One commenter suggested the performance was closely related to the size of the key, which would make sense. And I'm not worried about that. But I'm wondering if there's much difference between a 64 bit varchar, and a 64 bit integer?

Comment: I didn't read the article carefully yet, so it may not apply directly. But scanning the comments afteward did help to give me some insight. I just wanted to mention that, since I didn't see dj's comment before I posted my last one.

Answer (score 1):

You will *likely* not run out of integers.

For example in MySQL, max value for BigInt is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. So if you insert 100 million rows per second, it will take you 5849 years before you run out of numbers.

Comment: I was considering bigint's. But I read another thread here, and someone mentioned that some systems don't support bigint's. And it's possible I'll need to export data to one of those systems. So I'm trying to avoid having to convert bigint's to characters for systems like that. But I haven't ruled them out for sure yet.

Comment: @user568576, with "systems", do you mean different dbms or different operating systems?

Comment: "Application" would have been a better term. My users might need to export data, and use it in a spreadsheet, for example. Then they might want that data merged back in somehow.

Answer (score -1):

- varchar requires extra storage for length information
- comparison and sorting requires collation processing
- varchar may not match across systems because of collation
- int gives 4 billion rows, bigint (8 bytes) gives 18 trillion rows
- pre-bigint, I've seen decimal (19, 0) which also gives 18 trillion rows

Using varchar *will* end in tears...

To be clear: you're developing a system that may have more then 4 billion rows (you **don't know**), has replication, you **don't know** what RDBMS you'll use, and you don't understand how varchar differs from an integer?

Comment: To clarify: * All systems combined could have more than 4 billion rows. * Some of the data will need to be replicated. * I'm starting with firebird, but I may also need postgres. Different parts of the system will have different requirements. I may also change my mind. * That's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: I thought about the extra length info, and I don't think it'll matter. But collation stuff could be a problem. I'll need to do some more research on it.

Comment: I think I can avoid collation issues by using binary ordering. If I did that, would I have any problems matching across systems? My keys will just be a unique series of meaningless bits, so I'm thinking it won't matter how they're represented to the end user, if they happen to see them. Unless they export them, unknowingly convert them to some other character set, then somehow reimport them (I'm not ruling that out as a problem). Am I missing something important?