# Varchar or int for many records?

Tags: php, mysql, int, varchar

For a site like Facebook, does it use `int` or `varchar`? For example, for the number of posts on Facebook, there are billions or trillions. So do you use `int` for each post id or do you use `varchar`? The max for int is  2,147,483,647 so I'm confused. Please help, thanks.

Comment: `BIGINT` can handle 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 values, but sequence generation [eg: auto-increment] is a large barrier to parallelization, so chances are they use UUIDs or something similar instead.

Comment: @Sammitch sorry, what do you mean? i dont really understand

Comment: I quote [this answer on Stack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4638170/1415724): *"...in MySQL, max value for BigInt is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. So if you insert 100 million rows per second, it will take you 5849 years before you run out of numbers."*

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for the peace of mind! +1. LOVE the example!!!

Comment: Welcome; yeah it's pretty neat.

Answer (score 3):

there's also a BIGINT.

The signed range is -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807.

The unsigned range is 0 to 18446744073709551615.

That's more than enough :)

Comment: what about user id? do you think it can be `int`?

Comment: @JasonBale only for some period. Or later you can get situation with PSY Gangnam Style video clip. Google said that they never thought that any video could reach so much views

Answer (score 3):

As @Sammitch mentioned, UUID can generate a long value that has a much larger range than a 32-bit int. UUID generates a 128-bit value.

Also consider that a primary key can be a *compound primary key*, so you can expand the number of possibilities greatly.

You asked about user id. I did consulting for a site that ran out of values for their signed 32-bit INT user id. The reason was that because of a bug, they were skipping 1000 or more values for each new user that was created. So they ran out of values much faster than if they had been incrementing user ids 1 at a time.

I helped them upgrade their userid to BIGINT. We had to do this in the user table and in about 30 other tables that referenced the user table (because it would do no good to allow larger values for userid when the other tables are still using INT and can't reference the larger values).

See also my answer to [Integer overflow what will be next](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24007747/20860).

Comment: this is a perfect explanation. thanks for the real world example! +1